# CodeIgniter transfer from WAMP to host subfolder error

Tags: codeigniter

I was creating a simple CodeIgniter site on my WAMP and all runs well.

But when uploaded to the host it says `CI_Controller not found in CodeIgniter.php`

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home/<myhost>/public_html/pms/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233
```

I checked all the paths and seems right, i even went to the `CodeIgniter.php` file.

My database was migrated from local to the host, config was set, still this error comes out.

Is there something I'm missing? I really cant find anything on the net that could allow me to understand why it returns an error.

Hope someone could help understand this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter will most probably figure out the base_url by itself:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

... should work.

Comment: hmm.. this is strange. this was my base url:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://<mysite.com>/pms';`

then i change it to:

`$config['base_url'] = '';`

it worked. then again i change it to:

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://<mysite.com>/pms';`

it works as well, why didn't it worked the first time?

But well, @Mudshark thanks for the solution mate, its working on my host now...

Answer (score 0):

Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /home//public_html/pms/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 233

The path is not correct /home/public_html/pms/system/core/CodeIgniter.php